# How to disable contact showing after inserting contact

Tags: android

I use following code to insert a new contact from my app.

```
           Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION);
            intent.setType(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
            startActivity(intent);
```

On pressing back button, android saves the contact and returns to my app.

However, right after returning to my app, android suddenly shows the newly inserted contact on top of my app. I did not expect this.

Is there a way to disable showing the contact after it is inserted?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the answer in Android docs

```
            intent.putExtra("finishActivityOnSaveCompleted", true);
```

Please read section

> Add the navigation flag

http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/modify-data.html